# Data fields not populating when using xbbg & blp libraries for Bloomberg python API

Tags: python, pycharm, bloomberg, blpapi

Ok so I'm a college student with access and Bloomberg and I'm trying to connect an API to the terminal.

I downloaded the C++ supported release and had blpapi3_32.dll and blpapi3_64.dll copied over to the python installation location (Although I'm not sure if it should have been copied over to the PyCharm install location)

Long story short when I run the code the fields don't populate, and I have no idea why.  Thank you all in advance for the assistance!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVkGG.png)

Generally, do the installed packages have to be put in the same location as the file I'm writing the code on?  Sorry Noob question I'm just getting into all this.

I downloaded the C++ supported release and had blpapi3_32.dll and blpapi3_64.dll copied over to the python installation location (Although I'm not sure if it should have been copied over to the PyCharm install location)

I'm expecting the terminal to populate with two fields the security name which is Nvidia and the GICS Sector Name which is Information Technology

Comment: Please post the code and output directly into your question as text instead of inserting an image.

Comment: I don’t know much about `pycharm` but perhaps you need a `print` statement as you aren’t in an interactive shell? You aren’t getting any errors, so one assumes the function call is successful (especially as it’s a direct lift from the xbbg documentation).